# Как программно открывать и закрывать консоль python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pyqt5

Как в коде приложения `python` настроить открытие и закрытие консоли?

Я написал приложение `python` с помощью `PyQt` и мне требуется по нажатию кнопки **открывать и закрывать консоль**. Как это реализовать?

*Открытие консоли нужно для вывода побочной информации о работе программы с помощью `print()` во время каких-то действий пользователя (нажатие кнопок и т.д.)*

Comment: А почему прям в графичечском окне не сделать такой вывод? Или не писать его в файл?

Comment: Или пусть будет открыто что оно вам мешает?

Comment: @Александр в графическом окне и запись в файл не подходят для поставленной задачи. Скорее всего просто в настройках сборки оставлю активной консоль, вроде, не сильно мешает

Comment: А ты узнал спустя 4 года ? :>

Answer (score 1):

Короче я выяснил о существований pywin32... и типа прикол..

Вот пример кода в котором можно отключать и включать, код:

```
import tkinter as tk
import win32gui
import win32console
def hide_console(x):
    window = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
    win32gui.ShowWindow(window, x)
win = tk.Tk()
button1 = tk.Button(win, text="Скрыть", command=lambda:(hide_console(0)))
button1.pack()
button2 = tk.Button(win, text="Показать", command=lambda:(hide_console(1)))
button2.pack()
win.mainloop()

##########

import tkinter as tk
import win32gui
import win32console
def hide_console():
    window = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
    win32gui.ShowWindow(window, 0)
def show_console():
    window = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
    win32gui.ShowWindow(window, 1)
win = tk.Tk()
button1 = tk.Button(win, text="Скрыть", command=hide_console)
button1.pack()
button2 = tk.Button(win, text="Показать", command=show_console)
button2.pack()
win.mainloop()
```